# low version of php

Tags: pi-4, php

[image]

why does browser show the low version after I have updated the version of php

Comment: Hello and welcome! Have you tried rebooting the pi after the updates? You may also be able to reboot some services (eg, Nextcloud) to avoid it - but a reboot is the easiest and most fault proof way.